# Is it possible to copy files to a FTP using File.Copy?

Tags: c#, file, ftp, copy

Is it possible to use File.Copy to copy a file to a FTP server?

This is what I had in mind:

```
try
        {
            File.Copy(@"C:/test.txt", @"myFTP URL");
            MessageBox.Show("Copy Successfull.");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at the .Net FtpWebRequest class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brendan is right. Using the FtpWebRequest class I was able to upload files.